# Deploy locally trained model to SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cloud, amazon-sagemaker

I have a trained model in my local computer and I want to deploy it to SageMaker to create an endpoint. But I want to preprocess my data before push it to the model. What I have to prepare and how can I do it? (My model is a sklearn model)

I searched and almost pages just guide how to train and then deploy but I don't wanna train it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SageMaker "local" mode to test out your Inference, additionally use postman to make these Inference requests. An example can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/debugging-sagemaker-endpoints-quickly-with-local-mode-2975bd55f6f7a)